# Mapping Values Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I'm new-ish to rails and I get an error ("mapping values are not allowed in this context  ) when trying to run bundle commands or starting up the rails server. I've created a few rails apps and only recently started having this problem. Any possible fixes or solutions are much appreciated!

**What I'm Running**

- ruby 2.0.0p247
- rails 3.2.14
- bundler version 1.3.5
- homebrew 0.9.5
- rbenv 0.4.0

**Things I've Tried Already**

Based on other posts I've:

- checked the .gemrc file- nothing seems to be problematic. I've never used this file.
- checked database.yml. I haven't touched this, everything seems to be on the up and up
- tried loading the old YAML parser (syck) on boot.rb. It did not work :(
- brew doctor/update.
- rbenv rehash

**code**
all my code can be found on: github.com/owlbytes/AeroSoul

**full error**

```
/Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 1 column 26 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:318:in `load_file'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:191:in `initialize'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:319:in `new'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:319:in `configuration'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:34:in `configuration'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:53:in `sources='
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:250:in `remote_specs'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:163:in `fetch_specs'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:67:in `specs'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `block (2 levels) in index'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `each'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `block in index'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `index'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `resolve'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:109:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `run'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:320:in `update'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

**Update**
I was able to switch to ruby ruby 2.0.0p353. When I tried to update my bundler I got the following error:

/Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 1 column 26 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in`parse_stream'
from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in`load'
from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:319:in `load_file'
from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:192:in`initialize'
from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `new'
from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in`do_configuration'
from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:46:in `run'
from /Users/NehaShah/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/gem:21:in`'

Comment: Weird. I just downloaded your app and ran it locally. Looks fine to me. I'd say the only difference between my local and yours is ruby. Maybe use ruby 2.0.0p353 and see if that fixes it? And bundler v1.5.1.

Comment: It looks like I can't do anything bundler related --> including switching to bundler 1.5.1. If anyone has any ideas I'd appreciate it!

Comment: In case anyone finds this the following things were causing my errors:
 
(1) strange gemrc file. you can google what it's supposed to be. run subl ~/.gemrc in the terminal to open your gemrc file. 

(2) I had an rmagick issue where some gems needed rmagick but others needed RMagick. This was fixed by specifying in the gemfile:
gem 'rmagick', '2.13.2', :require =>"RMagick"

(3) After these two issues were fixed I was able to run bundle commands and everything started working.